# ClassNotFoundException for FileProvider on Samsung devices running Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, fileprovider

The issue only shows up on Samsung devices running Android 10, 100% in background according to Play Store crash reporting. We ship a library that our client integrates in their app, neither us or the client have managed to produce the crash in our own testing, and no other client has ever reported anything similar.

Our library has a custom FileProvider subclass in it, and our client is getting this crash on said devices:

```kotlin
Unable to get provider com.getstream.sdk.chat.StreamFileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.getstream.sdk.chat.StreamFileProvider" on path: DexPathList[
```

We've checked the client's APK, the provider is listed in their merged manifest correctly, and the class is there in the classes.dex file as well with correct bytecode contents.

Comment: Is this class in the primary DEX file? Anything unusual with the app setup (e.g., this is in a dynamic feature module)?

Comment: It is in the primary `classes.dex` file, yes. Nothing fancy like that in the app, all of this is in a regular APK.